# Is it possible to save scum the “Cash In on Ripened Flint” quest?

Tags: zelda-tears-of-the-kingdom

In the *Cash In on Ripened Flint* side quest Gomo a Gordon in Bedrock Bistro offers 1,000 rupees for a piece of ripened flint. Unfortunately he has to eat (consume) flint to determine if it is of the ripened variety. Link can offer flint in the amounts of 20, 50, or 100 pieces at a time. Rather than collecting enough flint for each attempt can this quest be [save scummed](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/96506/559)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Multiple sources have claimed they have save scummed/reloaded as needed.

[One source](https://www.neoseeker.com/zelda-tears-of-the-kingdom/sidequests/Cash_In_On_Ripened_Flint):

> If you want you can completely ignore this quest since giving him so much flint was just not worth the 1000 for me (yes, I save scummed here...)

[Second Source](https://thenerdstash.com/how-to-complete-cash-in-on-ripened-flint-in-zelda-tears-of-the-kingdom/):

> Save your game before completing the Cash In on Ripened Flint quest. In case of failure, you can restart your last save and try as many times as needed.