# What does the term “save scumming” mean?

Tags: terminology

What does the phrase “save scumming” mean? What is the origin of the phrase?

Answer (score 1):

Save scumming refers to the practice of repeatedly saving and reloading to manipulate outcomes or avoid unfavorable consequences. It is believed to have originated with players of the roguelike genre.

Comment: Doubtful on the latter, because one hallmark of a roguelike is that save scumming isn't actually possible without drastically interrupting the game before it can autosave into the save slot.

Comment: @shadur when I searched for the term I found multiple sources which indicated that was the origin. Probably should cite them here though. Just noticed that the question I didn’t find when I made this post last night is tagged with [roguelike].

Comment: @Shadur The top-voted answer at [What does it mean to "savescum"?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/96507/4797) says the same thing: "*The term originated in the Roguelike community […]*".